# Sort columns of a matrix(python3)

Tags: python, sorting, matrix, split

I have this code wrote in python 3 that is to input a matrix:

```
matrix = []
        loop = True
        while loop:
            line = input()
            if not line: 
                loop = False
                values = line.split()
                row = [int(value) for value in values]
                matrix.append(row)
```

this will results a matrix like:

```
9 2 6 3
0 3 4 2
2 1 1 0
```

My question is; how could I sort all the columns through a sort algorithm like shellsort:

```
inc = len(thelist) // 2
while inc:
    for i, el in enumerate(thelist):
        while i >= inc and thelist[i - inc] > el:
            thelist[i] = thelist[i - inc]
            i -= inc
        thelist[i] = el
    inc = 1 if inc == 2 else int(inc * 5.0 / 11)
```

and it would result the sorted matrix:

```
0 1 1 0
2 2 4 2
9 3 6 3
```

I tried so far to split the columns

```
col = line.split(line, ',')
```

But it doesnt work.I want to do this without external library such as numpy or others.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to sort by column as though each column were a word or just sort each column like in your example?

Comment: I want to sort all the columns like in my example,but by passing each columns into a sort algorithm like in my question,and then return them sorted in the matrix and at the right column position they were before.Thanks

Comment: Consider accepting one of the answers below, or clarify how they don't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
def sortmatrix(matrix):
    length, width = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)
    dup = [item for sub in matrix for item in sub]             
    dup = sorted(dup)
    i = 0                                                           
    new_list = [dup[i:i+length] for i in range(len(dup)) if i %length == 0]
    return new_list
```

This code runs as:

```
>>> def sortmatrix(matrix):
...     length, width = len(matrix[0]), len(matrix)
...     dup = [item for sub in matrix for item in sub]             
...     dup = sorted(dup)
...     i = 0                                                           
...     new_list = [dup[i:i+length] for i in range(len(dup)) if i %length == 0]
...     return new_list
...                                 ... 
>>> sortmatrix([['9', '2', '6', '3'], ['0', '3', '4', '2'], ['2', '1', '1', '0']])
[['0', '0', '1', '1'], ['2', '2', '2', '3'], ['3', '4', '6', '9']]
>>>
```

Comment: But I need it to be sort with a sort algorithm I already have,wich basically sort a list of integers; see my edit for sort algorithm im talking about

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, python makes it extremely difficult to sort a list of lists by column (numpy arrays make this much easier). Assuming you don't want to / can't use them, you could take the transpose of your matrix, sort the resulting rows, and then apply a second transpose.

sort_func is whatever sorting function you have defined (I just used sorted)

e.g.,

```
>>> a = [[1,3,5],[0,9,5],[2,1,5]]

>>> at = [[row[i] for row in a] for i in range(len(a))]

>>> ats = [sort_func(row) for row in at]

>>> atst = [[row[i] for row in ats] for i in range(len(ats))]

>>> atst

[[0, 1, 5], [1, 3, 5], [2, 9, 5]]

>>> a

[[1, 3, 5], [0, 9, 5], [2, 1, 5]]
```

If numpy arrays aren't a problem for you, I'd say do something akin to the following:

```
a = np.array(a)

for j in range(a.shape[1]):

    a[:,j] = sort_func(a[:,j])
```

Comment: In general, sorting each row separately gives different results from sorting the columns, since the last row will be less significant than the first.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon the example provided in the question maintained the values contained in each column while sorting their position in the column. The location of a given column did not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose your matrix using the following code:

```
def transpose(matrix):
    return map(list, zip(*matrix))
```

So your sorting can do this to sort the columns if you have a code to sort a matrix by row (I've used the built-in `sorted` function here):

```
transpose(sorted(transpose(matrix))
```

If you want to sort each column's elements independently, you can just map sort over the columns

```
transpose(map(sorted, transpose(matrix)))
```